# bootstrap navbar-collapse menu extends beyond view in portrait mode of a device with a small height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with a Bootstrap dropdown menu extending beyond the height of the device when viewed in landscape mode on an iPhone (or any device with a small screen). The scrollbar displays but it too extends too far off the screen and is of no use in scrolling.

Example is at: http://dev.backcountryaccess.com/

Please let me know if I should be posting this as a jsFiddle as well, but thought it was easiest to just post the link...

Would prefer a CSS fix but anything that works would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to embed one in the question, but here is the dropbox link to a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wi1nc4ozma6lzek/dev.backcountryaccess.com.png

Comment: The scrollbar is visible here, right?

Comment: it's visible, but doesn't actually work to scroll down to the last two items. As you can see the scrollbar doesn't fit within the window either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're still having such a issue but thought I'd give my solution with jQuery:

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
    $(".navbar-collapse").css({ maxHeight: $(window).height() - $(".navbar-header").height() + "px" });
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of padding on top of the navbar li items.
use a @media query to shrink the padding on smaller devices. You have

```
   .navbar-nav > li {
   padding-top: 30px;
```

Add an addiontal style with a media query:

```
 @media (max-width: 381px) {
 .navbar-nav > li {
   padding-top: 10px;
   }
  }
```

Or to whatever size you feel is appropriate. Only thing I could think of for a quick fix.

Or the opposite with

```
  @media (min-width: 381px) {
 .navbar-nav > li {
   padding-top: 30px;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Russell, this is what I've been looking into. I believe the main trouble is in the entire <div class="navbar-collapse in"> being too high and extending beyond the short screen size of a phone in landscape mode. So even if I reduced the padding for the <li> items, many of them have dropdowns when clicked which still won't show as they'll extend beyond the device height...

Comment: It's even an issue in Bootstrap's own example (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) if viewed on an iPhone in landscape and you click on the example dropdown the menu items extend beyond the screen...

Comment: yea @dman, that's right, especially because it's fixed. Otherwise you could scroll the page. I guess there isn't a good solution for landscape except maybe hiding certain items with media query. Or display: none.